# Styling for UINavigationBar not working in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am having trouble getting custom styling for my UINavigationBar, set in a subclass of UIViewController.

I've had this working before and not sure why its not working here.

I have the following code in my view controller:

```
- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds; 

    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    frame.size = [navBar sizeThatFits:frame.size];
    [navBar setFrame:frame];
    [navBar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    // The following styling has no effect:
    [navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [navBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]; 
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];

    UIBarButtonItem * button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay
        target:self  
        action:@selector(nextView:)];                                                                                                                                                        

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
    [button release];
    [navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationItem]];

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

}
```

Comment: is this a subclass of UIViewController to the point where let's call this subclass CustomViewController such that ALL your viewcontrollers of of type class "customviewcontroller"?

Comment: If this is the case, then I can show you how to do this, programmatically, in fact I have an example of the method sitting around here somewhere right now, but it's complex and I dont' want to confuse you if this isn't what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mess with the UINavigationBar by initialising a new one and adding it as a subview. Instead, use the possibilities of `UINavigationBar.appearance`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor;
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor;
```

Please note that this changes the appearance of the UINavigationBar everywhere in the app, hence `appearance`. If this isn't what you want, you could try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor;
```

Comment: Who told to add it as a subview? In storyboard you can just set the class of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: I'm doing it all programmatically, no storyboards here.

Answer (score -1):

I did styling using subclassing. Example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavBar : UINavigationBar

@end


#import "CustomNavBar.h"

@implementation CustomNavBar

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect1.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                               [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect1);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImage *bgImage = img;
    [bgImage drawInRect:rect];

    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.1);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

}

@end
```